# Monotony of generated sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

So the generated sigma-algebra is the smallest sigma algebra over $\Omega$ containing a set A. And one of its properties is that if A is a subset of B then so is $\sigma(A)$ a subset of $\sigma(B)$. But here is where I think I misunderstood something because, if we have lets say $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ then $\sigma(\Omega)=\{\{\},\Omega\}$, since it is the smallest sigma-algebra containing $\Omega$. But lets now take a subset $A=\{1,2\}$. Here we have $\sigma(A)=\{\{\},\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\Omega\}$. But now even though A is a subset of $\Omega$ we have that $\sigma(A)$ is not a subset of $\sigma(\Omega)$. I think I misunderstood the concept and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $A$ and $B$ must be subsets of $\Omega$ (note otherwise $A\subseteq \sigma(A)$ wouldn't make any sense). In this case you have $\sigma(\{\Omega\})$ and $\sigma(\{\{1,2\}\})$. $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is not a subset of $\{\Omega\}$, so there is no contradiction here.

Comment: So as I understand it my misconception stemmed from thinking that $A, \Omega$ are subsets of $P(\Omega)$ which they are not. But $\{A\},\{\Omega\}$ are the associated subsets and since $\{A\}=\{\{1,2\}\}$ is not a subset of $\{\Omega\}=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ there is no contradiction to monotony. I hope I understood it correctly now.